# Axios does not pass (data) to the request

Tags: javascript, php, request, axios

Sorry for my English!
I work with Axios not so long ago, I am constantly tormented. Actually, I need to transfer the “data” from Vue through Axios for myself to the PHP controller, after the Axios method is triggered, I do dd ($ request) and see the void, tell me what could be the problem, thanks!

P.S. I am still confused that the 'data' in the console is displayed in 'config' and in the field 'data' above some kind of giant script is above the config. So it should be? or is there a problem? (see screenshots of the console below).

```html
<div id="blank">
  <form>
    <div class="form-grup">
     <label></label>
     <input type="text" class="myform" name="kladr" v-model="kladr">
    </div>
    <div class="form-grup">
     <label></label>
     <input type="text" class="myform" name="ownerKladr" v-model="ownerKladr">
    </div>
    <div class="form-grup">
     <label></label>
     <input type="text" class="myform" name="insurancePeriod" v-model="insurancePeriod">
    </div>
    <button @click.prevent="storeBlank">Accept</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

```js
var blankjs = new Vue({
   el: '#blank',
   data() {
     return {
       kladr: '',
       ownerKladr: '',
           insurancePeriod: ''
        }
      },

methods: {

  storeBlank() {

    let url = '/blank/' + encodeURIComponent(this.user) + '/save';

    let data = {
   kladr: this.kladr,
    ownerKladr: this.ownerKladr,
    insurancePeriod: this.insurancePeriod
    } 

      axios.post(url, data)

      .then(function (response) {
        console.log(response)      
      })
    }
  }
})
```

```php
 // PHP

  /**
  * @Route("/blank/{user}/save", name="save_blank")
  */
public function storeBlank(Request $request, User $user): Response
   {

   dd($request); //or dd(json_encode($request));

   }
```

This is what I get in console.log:

```html
data: "<script> Sfdump = window.Sfdump || (function (doc)…re><script>Sfdump("sf-dump-1008019515")</script>↵", status: 200, statusText: "OK", headers: {…}, config: {…}, …}

config:
  adapter: ƒ (e)
    data: "{"data":{"kladr":"", "ownerKladr":"", "insurancePeriod":""}}"
    headers: 
      Accept: "application/json, text/plain, */*"
      Content-Type: "application/json;charset=utf
```

Comment: Everything looks find from the client-side (JS). What PHP framework are you using?

Comment: I use Symfony4 framework

Comment: https://github.com/symfony-bundles/json-request-bundle

Answer (score -1):

Your data is inside of data object. Here is example:

```
axios.post(url, data)
.then(function (response) {
    console.log(response.data);      
 });
```

Also your request can be failed. You can handle error witch `catch` method.

```
axios.post(url, data)
.catch(function(error){
    //if your request fail this block will be executed. otherwise 'then' statement will work
})
.then(function (response) {
    console.log(response.data);      
 });
```